# SSRS Parent Row Group leaves spaces with Datetime

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, grouping, ssrs-2012, removing-whitespace

Im new to SSRS. So I sort the columns by date. And I want to remove the duplication of date datetime value which I converted in SQL Query DataSet.

This is the image:

[Click Here For Sample Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be1YV.png)

Then I try to add parent row by ModifiedDate or having an expression under visibility of:

`=Fields!ModifiedDate.Value = Previous(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value)`

`=Fields!ModifiedDate.Value = NOTHING`

Then the output leaves spaces.

[Click Here For Sample Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8j1f.png)

How do I remove the white/free below the first datetime value spaces?

Comment: Hi There- If I understand this right you have detail rows that are showing the same date.  I *think* you want a group by the date in addition to what you already group by.  So add another group by that date.  OR if you do not mean to show multiple rows per date, then you can distinct your dataset so the detail rows do not repeat the data.

Comment: Have you tried using the **HideDuplicates** property of the **Modified By Date** text box?